# How to save the profile, so that we can list questions of specific tags group that we know about?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I know we can make [php][perl] on our search box.

Is there a way to save that for subsequent site visits, so that, each time we want to see the questions list, we can see only the ones we are interested in, without doing [php][javascript][c#] again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could make a bookmark in your browser to the following url :)

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+perl
```

Comment: That will do. Is not a in-site solution, but it's a solution. :-)